# USB ports stop working on boot (Lenovo Desktop)

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo-desktop-computer

I've had an old Lenovo Desktop for a while. Its specs are i5-6400, 16gb Crucial ram, RX 550, and the Lenovo Skybay mobo it's had since I got it. I tripped on a wire and the pc fell down around 3 days ago. It boots and works fine, but the usb ports have stopped working. On post, it doesn't show that a usb device is connected. My mouse and keyboard light up and work fine at post, but once it gets to boot they stop working. Since I can't use my keyboard and mouse to enter the password, I can't use my computer. I've opened it up and checked the mobo, and all the wires and pins seem to be plugged in correctly. Is there any way to fix this? NOTE: I can't access BIOS, because Lenovo computers are so locked down. It asks me for a password that I don't know. Also, I added one of the 8gb ram sticks and the gpu.

Comment: Where did you get the PC from? Lenovo does not lock down BIOS. You or someone else did that..  You need to contact the seller or look in your notes.

Comment: I don't know where it was bought from, I got it as a present for christmas around 5 years ago. Maybe it was the previous owner, but I can't contact them easily and there is a high possibility that they have forgotten it too.

Comment: Depending on the age of the machine, Lenovo Service would replace the motherboard. Make sure it is worth saving.

Comment: It's definitely worth saving. This is my personal computer and it has all of my important files on it. Are you sure there's not anything else I can do? (Note: It's from 2015)

Comment: You need to call Lenovo Service and ask them.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: The computer isn't under warranty. Can I still get the motherboard replaced?

Comment: You need to ask them if they have the board for it. Look also on eBay with the specific model.

Comment: Perhaps a repair-shop can find a bad contact.

Comment: When out of warranty independent repair shops are usually a better (and cheaper) option. Manufacturers really don't want to have anything to do with you, except for selling you a new machine, when the warranty expires and with it their legal obligations of customer support. Lenovo may still have the required part but they'll charge you a lot more than it's worth.